# Django to serve static files with exceptions

Tags: django, url, static

In my production environment I have Nginx serving static files for my Django application, but while developing I let Django so the work.

I need to have Nginx serving all static files *but* those in a certain subdirectory. So, Django side, I need to intercept that directory and treat it differently.

How can I make Django dev server intercept all the calls to `/static/*` but not those to `/static/myspecialfiles/*´ and hence write a url route to handle the GET calls to said`/static/myspecialfiles/*´?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tackle this in two areas, Django and nginx.

For Django, since running a local setup (when `DEBUG=True`) already serves static content from `STATIC_ROOT` automatically, just add a URL conf for your special files:

```
# in urls.py
url(r'^/static/specialfiles/', SpecialView.as_view(), name='special'),
```

Then, in your nginx conf, make sure you ignore that path so it actually reaches Django:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

    location /static/specialfiles/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/dev/example/static/;
    }
}
```

Since the locations are parsed sequentially, your special files will hit the django block before the generic static block.

But really you'd be best to just move your special files somewhere else.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what i've done, but i'm under the impression that my url dispatcher is never reached and that static files are served *before*. if i comment out 'django.contrib.staticfiles', from INSTALLED_APPS, that url gets intercepted, otherwise not.

Comment: I was under the impression the static confs are appended to your conf, but looks like this isn't the case. I stick with my suggestion to move your files elsewhere.